# beamer theme change of outline in to the left side

Tags: beamer

How to get the outline of a ppt on the left side of the beamer like this I have attached an image:
[image: U can see the image below]

Is there any package that can convert this thing? I know the outline are on the above on the top like this:

[image: blue theme]

Is there any package available to take outline to the left side?

Comment: That depends on the used theme. Have a look at an overview page, e.g. [here](https://deic-web.uab.cat/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html) and select one. Maybe `Hannover` or `PaloAlto`.

Comment: @dexteritas thank you so much